# In the Chemistry Development Kit (CDK) IMolecule interface is missing

Tags: cheminformatics

It seems like the interface IMolecule has been obsoleted and replaced by something else. Any idea what the replacement is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IMolecule` has been removed because the only addition to the `IAtomContainer` API was the concept that the content of the `IMolecule` was fully connected. For the migration, everywhere where you wrote `IMolecule` just write `IAtomContainer` now.